# opencv3.1dnn unhandled exception

Tags: opencv, dotnetnuke, unhandled-exception, opencv3.1

I'm following the instruction of `opencv` online documentation to load a caffe framework model. But there is an `unhandled exception` when I execute to the code `net.forward()` at the 80th line. Following is the error information.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (input.dims() == 4 && (input.type() == CV_32F ||
input.type() == CV_64F)) in cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::allocate, file C:\Use
rs\chang\Desktop\opencv_contrib-master\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.
cpp, line 89
```

I really have no idea about this exception.Waiting for any reply.Thanks!
opencv dnn online document:http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html
opencv extra_contrib dnn samples:https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/dnn/samples

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace

```
dnn::Blob inputBlob = dnn::Blob(img);
```

with

```
dnn::Blob inputBlob = dnn::Blob::fromImages(img);
```